# How to use UserUttered in Rasa 1.X?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

With Rasa 1.5.3, when the user says something to our chatbot but this chatbot does not understand clearly, we want to autocorrect the user input and send it back to the NLU pipeline in order for Rasa to understand it.

We tried to use the UserUttered event in our default_fallback action, but this does not work :
When using :

```
from rasa_sdk import Action
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet, AllSlotsReset, Restarted, UserUtteranceReverted, FollowupAction, ActionReverted, UserUttered
from rasa_sdk.forms import FormAction, REQUESTED_SLOT
from rasa_sdk.events import SlotSet

class ActionDefaultFallback(Action):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def name(self):
        return "action_default_fallback"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        text = tracker.latest_message['text']
        correct_text = my_custom_spellcheck.correct(text)

        return UserUttered(text=correct_text)
```

Running this default_fallback_action just gives us this error :

```
2021-01-19 11:59:05 ERROR    rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_default_fallback'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of your action server for more information.
```

How to use the UserUttered event ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions need to return a list of events, so your `run` method should return `[UserUttered(text=correct_text)]`. See [here](https://rasa.com/docs/action-server/sdk-actions) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by auto correct? It usually better to introduce misspelled nlu examples directly into your nlu training data.
Otherwise, I would recommend to create a custom NLU component with your spellchecker and add it to your NLU pipeline before the tokenizer.